# Is there most simple dataset for CNN training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution

I'm searching for 2-class convolutional neural network problem published as paper using smallest-dataset.

Generally CNN requires millions of images to train ,but I found it successfully works with hundreds to thousands of 2-class images through augmentation. I need to prove it by citing other best practices.

The similar case I found is "Mitosis detection in breast cancer histology images with deep neural networks" it trained on 190 positive samples and other images on the background. and it had quite successful result.

Is there another successful 2-class problem CNN research with small dataset?

Comment: Since this isn't a programming question, it belongs on CrossValidated.

Comment: thanks I uploaded this question on cross validated too.

Comment: any answers? Or what is the link in CrossValidated?